# Why does finding the average in a proc means and a proc sql step yield different results according to a proc compare?

Tags: sql, sas, compare, mean, sas-macro

I have the following code. The datasets created are `test_means` and `test_sql`. Both are taking the simple average of a variable of your choice.

Both create exactly the same number by `eye`.

Why is it that the `proc compare` says the values are unequal to a stupidly small value, like 0E-14? Is this something to do with the way numbers are stored in both procedures?

```
%let var=; *Insert numeric variable to check;
%let dsn=; *Insert dataset name;

proc means noprint mean data=&dsn.;
    var &var.;
    output out=test_means (keep=_STAT_ &var. where=(_STAT_="MEAN"));
run;

proc sql;
    create table test_sql as select
        "MEAN" as _STAT_ length=8,
        mean(&var.) as &var.
    from &dsn.
    ;
quit;

proc compare data=test_means compare=test_sql;
run;
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for PROC COMPARE.  Specifically the METHOD= option.

Comment: I assume it is just rounding error caused by using floating point numbers. Wasn't there a recent post where someone showed an example where the order that data is processed impacted the result of the operations?

Comment: Those are not significant differences. Look at the FUZZ option in PROC COMPARE or numerical precision in software.

Comment: I completely understand that they're not _significant_ differences, but they're differences nonetheless and I'm probably going to be asked to explain them. Order of operations sounds like a good shout, I'll get reading.

Comment: Differences on the order of `E-14` are not differences in any meaningful sense - not just not *significant*, but they're not actual differences.  Anything below `E-12` should be disregarded as an artifact of how computers store things, unless you're specifically doing work that expects differences of that magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differences on the order of `E-14` are to be expected from calculations done on floating point values (as SAS numbers are).  This isn't particularly related to the different PROCs; all it would take would be summing values in a different order to produce an error along those lines.  Even two different runs in `PROC SQL` could generate differences of this magnitude, if rows end up processed differently (due to multithreading, for example).

`PROC COMPARE` runs should generally be done with the `FUZZ` option, unless you are comparing numbers with very small magnitudes.  This should usually be part of standard practice, unless you specifically want to see this kind of difference (meaning, unless you want to verify two files are the same file, and not just the same values).